# Why am I not seeing plot in bokeh application server?

Tags: python, bokeh, dashboard

I am learning bokeh and I am making an application. I ran the directory using the schema given in the documentation `bokeh serve --show app`, the code runs successfully and I see the rendering of template and CSS as I expected, but I do not see the plot that I want to generate.

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/weather/main.py

I followed this and also looked on Stackoverflow where it was advised to use `curdoc()`, but I still do not see the plot. I am using Python 3.6 and Bokeh 0.13.0 Firefox 61.0 and OS Ubuntu

This is my complete code for main.py

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row

p = figure(title='One sample graph',
            plot_width=700,
            plot_height=700,
            toolbar_location=None)

p.circle([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,2,5,4], size=15)

curdoc().add_root(row(p))
```

I also looked at the terminal to see if there were any errors there. It also did not have any error and when I looked at the source code of HTML server, I did not see the code for generating the plot. Am I missing something? Please help.

Edit 1:

I looked at the following tutorial also. This has application without any templates and CSS and doesn't solve my problem.

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-bokeh-in-python-part-iii-a-complete-dashboard-dc6a86aa6e23

Edit 2: Here is the output window of the terminal. 
[image]

Here is the output when I simply run bokeh serve --show main.py In this case, I only see the plot and lose my template and CSS information. I have also downloaded Chrome to see if there was a problem with the browser, but it is not.

[image]

Am I missing something in my code? On gitter, I was informed of using server_document() also, where do I place that statement in my document so that everything gets rendered properly?

Comment: What is the console output in the window where you ran `bokeh serve`? What is the JS console output in browser debug window? I just ran your code above and it worked as expected.

Comment: Hi, I have added some other information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running with `bokeh serve --show appdir`, `templates/index.html` displayed, but the original template did not contain any calls to `embed` to specify where plots should go, so no plots showed up. It is necessary to call `embed` in the template so that Bokeh knows where to put the plots. The updated template which uses `embed` in `index.html` looks like so:

main.py:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row 

p = figure(title='One sample graph',
            plot_width=700,
            plot_height=700,
            toolbar_location=None)

p.circle([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,2,5,4], size=15)

curdoc().add_root(row(p, name='plotrow'))
```

templates/index.html:

```
{% extends base %}
{% block preamble %}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/static/special.css">
{% endblock %}
{% block contents %}
<title>Dashboard</title>
<div class="background">
<div class="header">
<h1>Text</h1>
<h2>Some more text</h2>
<p>Even more text</p>
</div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="container">{{ embed(roots.plotrow) }}</div>
<div class="footer">
<p>Some extra text <br/>By someone</p>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```